# Can you arc diff against a particular git branch?

Tags: git, phabricator, arcanist

I'm pretty new to both Arcanist and git. I'd like to be able to create an arc diff (Phabricator Differential instance using Arcanist) against a git branch that I'm currently checked-out/working in (and I have one local un-pushed commit) rather than the master. To me the [arc docs](http://www.phabricator.com/docs/phabricator/article/Arcanist_User_Guide_arc_diff.html) are unclear on this. Is it possible? How? It would be nice if the answer works for 2-3 local un-pushed commits as well.

Also "arc help diff" gives:

```
      diff [paths] (svn)
      diff [commit] (git, hg)
          Supports: git, svn, hg
          Generate a Differential diff or revision from local changes.

          Under git, you can specify a commit (like HEAD^^^ or master)
          and Differential will generate a diff against the merge base of that
          commit and HEAD.
```

Maybe I just need to do "arc diff [commit]" where [commit] is the tip of the target branch? But I'd like to be certain, because I don't want to pollute our Phabricator instance.

Also, I'm happy to receive "you're doing it wrong" answers if the answer explains how to do it right.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In general, `arc diff <branch>` will do what you want. (If you're already on the branch, rather than a local topic branch, try `arc diff origin/<branch>` instead.)

When invoked like this, `arc` will actually diff against the `merge-base` of the branch's tip and the current commit in the working copy, but generally this is what you intend. If you really want to generate a diff against the branch tip you can use `arc diff --base git:<branch>`, but this diff will include changes which *undo* any commits on the `branch` which are descendants of the branch point, just like `git diff <branch>..HEAD` would.

In all cases, you can use `arc which <commit>` to preview what `arc diff` will do. This will explain which revision range would be selected, show you the command to see exactly which changes are included, and explain why that range is selected.

You can also use `arc diff --preview` to generate just a diff, without sending it for review. This will let you preview changes before submitting them to anyone else.

See also:

https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/arcanist_commit_ranges/

Comment: link should be updated to https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/arcanist_commit_ranges/

Comment: for generating diff against the branch tip I used `arc diff --base 'git:branch-unique(origin/master)'` which generates a diff against the tip of `origin/master`

running `arc diff  --preview --base git:<branch>` did not match the results I wanted.

Comment: Once <branch> has landed onto master, how do I land my revision onto master, not onto <branch>?

Comment: `arc diff origin/<branch>` this worked for me thanks

Answer (score 4):

Evan's answer is generally preferable because it is more reflective of best git workflow practices. I recommend following that if you can.

If you need a quick fix and are working in (checked out) the same branch that you want to push to, you can also do `arc diff HEAD^` or `HEAD~` for a single commit, or `arc diff HEAD~N` for N commits.